# Did the Teleri ever forgive the Noldor for the Kinslaying at Alqualondë?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

It was a tragedy caused by Fëanor,  who wanted revenge for his father's death and killed many Sea Elves for their ships, but is there anything in Tolkien's Letters or *The History of Middle-Earth* that tells us if the Teleri eventually forgave the Noldor for what they had done to their ships and kin-elves or are we just to think the Teleri never forgave the Noldor, and hated them forever?

Comment: What's with the tildes on the initial N in Noldor? I've never seen it spelled like that, and you did it too consistently for it to be a typo...

Comment: i didnt spell it like that it was Wad Cheber who edited it

Comment: @Fingolfin - That's the (more) correct spelling, but if you like it the other way, so be it. http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Noldor

Comment: "The spelling Ñoldor rather than Noldor was used by Tolkien in his later writings (the character ñ signifying the velar nasal, the sound found in the English word "sing"), but even in earlier versions the name Ñoldo came from a Primitive Quendian stem *ñgolodō, which led to Ñoldo in Quenya and Golodh in Sindarin."

Comment: @MikeHarris - see above.

Comment: Couldn't let the "Gnomes" thing go ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be at least a partial reconciliation.

> Because Fëanor had taken the ships and left the Noldor led by his half-brother on the west side of the sea, the royal houses of the Noldor were feuding, but Fingon son of Fingolfin, saved Maedhros, son of Fëanor, from Morgoth's imprisonment and the feud was settled. Maedhros was due to succeed Fëanor, but he regretted his part of the Kinslaying and the abandonment of Fingolfin and left the High Kingship of the Noldor to his uncle Fingolfin because he was the eldest, who became the first High King of the Noldor in Middle-earth.  - <sub>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noldor#Exile_to_Middle-earth)</sub>

**Celeborn**<sup>Teleri</sup> and Celebrimbor were, in one account, two of the four Falmari to leave Valinor with **Galadriel** <sup>greatest of the Noldor save Fëanor</sup>.

They were of course married°:
°[Source](http://lotrproject.com/)

> Galadriel and Celeborn sailed from the West and came to Beleriand **separately from the two main hosts of the Noldor** (one that **Fëanor led in the ships of the Teleri**, the other led by Fingolfin and Finrod that crossed the Helcaraxë)¹
>   ¹[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galadriel#Internal_biography)

[image: GaladrielCeleborn]

Comment: This answer is not very satisfying. "Yes" in one account (that did not get worked into the Silmarillion because it would have required massive rewrites of other sections to retcon Galadriel's departure from Valinor) Celeborn is Teleri, but: 1) they left together prior to the kinslaying so Galadriel would be blameless; 2) Celeborn would be *a teleri* not *the teleri*; and 3) Celeborn was not wronged except by association.

Comment: They certainly [knew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galadriel#Internal_biography) `Galadriel and Celeborn sailed from the West and came to Beleriand separately from the two main hosts of the Noldor (one that Fëanor led in the ships of the Teleri, the other led by Fingolfin and Finrod that crossed the Helcaraxë)` about the rift. Also your assertion regarding them leaving **together** is clearly inaccurate.  My entire premise was to find an example of the two factions working together or marriage etc.

Comment: `and Celeborn of Doriath, with
Galadriel his wife, who alone remained of those who led the
Noldor to exile in Beleriand.` - Sillmarilion

Comment: Your first quote says that they departed together but separately from the Noldor so yeah, what I said is totally accurate. In your last quote Celeborn was Sindarin (of the people of Doriath). He is only Teleri in a very late unpublished story snippet that Christopher Tolkein chose not to integrate into the Silmarillion because it would have forced him to rewrite other parts of the exodus story. So like I said originally, in one account (only) is Celeborn a Teleri and in that single account, Galadriel and Celeborn departed together separately and before the Host of the Noldor.

Comment: In fact the whole purpose behind JRRT trying to do this so late is to get Galadriel into a position of being blameless in the kinslaying

Comment: I knew it was added after the fact, but didn't realize it was to remove blame, I thought, that rewrite was to elevate Celeborn to her level. I stand corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Surprisingly simple answer; yes, they did (emphasis mine):

> And when they came into the West the Elves of Beleriand dwelt upon Tol Eressëa, the Lonely Isle, that looks both west and east; whence they might come even to Valinor. They were admitted again to the love of Manwë and the pardon of the Valar; and **the Teleri forgave their ancient grief**, and the curse was laid to rest.
>
> <sup>*The Silmarillion* III *Quenta Silmarillion* Chapter 24: "Of the Voyage of Eärendil and the War of Wrath"</sup>

Finarfin's people, who turned away from the rest of the Noldor after hearing the Prophecy of the North, also received a pardon from the Valar (emphasis mine):

> But in that hour Finarfin forsook the march, and turned back, being filled with grief, and with bitterness against the House of Fëanor, because of his kinship with Olwë of Alqualondë; and many of his people went with him, retracing their steps in sorrow, until they beheld once more the far beam of the Mindon upon Túna still shining in the night, and so came at last to Valinor. **There they received the pardon of the Valar**, and Finarfin was set to rule the remnant of the Noldor in the Blessed Realm.
>
> <sup>*The Silmarillion* III *Quenta Silmarillion* Chapter 9: "OF the Flight of the Noldor"</sup>

Whether or not this group was forgiven by the Teleri at this time is unrecorded.