# Did Thingol ever forgive the House of Fingolfin for the Kinslaying at Alqualondë?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

Thingol was originally the leader of the [Nelyar](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Nelyar) Elves awoken in Middle-Earth. This title was later given to his brother. Thingol then became first King of the Northern Elven Kingdom of Doriath. Being akin to the Teleri of Aman, he was furious upon learning of the First Kinslaying and thus disliked the Host of Fëanor, who caused it.

He remained on friendly terms with the House of Finarfin in Middle-earth, though, as they had not participated in the Kinslaying. He allowed Finrod and Galadriel, children of Finarfin, to stay in his land as guests. He specifically disliked the House of Fëanor, as they had started the Kinslaying. This feeling further deteriorated after he was threatened to handover the Silmaril.

**Is it stated anywhere in the books whether Thingol forgave the House of Fingolfin, or had any interaction with them at all, or did he hold a grudge with them that is explicitly shown?**

<sub>NOTE: This is not a duplicate of [Did the Teleri ever forgive the Noldor for the Kinslaying at Alqualondë?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112794/did-the-teleri-ever-forgive-the-noldor-for-the-kinslaying-at-alqualond%C3%AB) I am asking about the relationship between Thingol and the House of Fingolfin.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I couldn't find much, however in *The Silmarillion* Thingol speaks of the House of Fingolfin and the deeds they carried out at Alqualondë. <sub>(Emphasis mine)</sub>

> But Thingol was long silent ere he spoke. ‘Go now!’ he said. ‘For my heart is hot within me. Later you may return, if you will; for I will not shut my doors for ever against you, my kindred, that were ensnared in an evil that you did not aid. **With Fingolfin and his people also I will keep friendship, for they have bitterly atoned for such ill as they did.** And in our hatred of the Power that wrought all this woe our griefs shall be lost.
> <sub>The Silmarillion: Chapter 15, Of the Noldor in Beleriand</sub>

Thingol however does such not without cost. He decreed that henceforth, Noldorin Quenya should be forbidden from being spoken in Doriath and any who do will be deemed kinslayers.

> But hear my words! Never again in my ears shall be heard the tongue of those who slew my kin in Alqualondë! Nor in all my realm shall it be openly spoken, while my power endures. All the Sindar shall hear my command that they shall neither speak with the tongue of the Noldor nor answer to it. And all such as use it shall be held slayers of kin and betrayers of kin unrepentant.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>

This came at great cost to the Noldorin language, due to the exiles living in Doriath being unable to use their language, it waned and was kept mostly by the Lords, and kept as a language of lore.

> And it came to pass even as Thingol had spoken; for the Sindar heard his word, and thereafter throughout Beleriand they refused the tongue of the Noldor, and shunned those that spoke it aloud; but the Exiles took the Sindarin tongue in all their daily uses, and the High Speech of the West was spoken only by the lords of the Noldor among themselves. Yet that speech lived ever as a language of lore, wherever any of that people dwelt.
> <sub>ibid.</sub>